# Handling flatlist with numcolumn more than 2 if render Item returns null

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

```js
<FlatList
    data={["1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2",]}
    renderItem={
      ({ item }) => {
        if(item==="1"){
          return(
            <View style={styles.box}>
                <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>)
        }
      }
    }
    numColumns={2}
    columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent:'space-around'}}
/>
```

Here is my code and my goal is to make result just the same as:

```js
<FlatList
    data={["1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]}
    renderItem={
      ({ item }) => {
        if(item==="1"){
          return(
            <View style={styles.box}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>)
        }
      }
    }
    numColumns={2}
    columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent:'space-around'}}
/>
```

I am trying really hard with this issue and I cannot find any answers on google or StackOverflow.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the first code fragment to render the same UI as the second code fragment, that is, to still have 2 columns. If that is the desired behaviour, you can filter your data before supplying it to `FlatList`:

```js
<FlatList
    data={["1","2","1","2","1","2","1"].filter(element => element === "1")}
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can render an empty `View` in place of elements that don't meet your condition (in this case, you will have 2 columns, with 'empty' cells for elements that are !== "1"):

```js
<FlatList
    data={["1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2","1","2",]}
    renderItem={
          ({ item }) => {
            if (item === '1'){
              return (
                <View style={styles.box}>
                  <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>)
            } else {
              return <View/>
            }
          }
        }
    ...
```